# Получить информация об устройстве Android на Java

Tags: java, android

Как получить характеристики телефона Android: количество ядер CPU, частота ядер CPU, общий объем ОЗУ и жесткого диска, разрешение камеры(основной и фронтальной). Смог получить только объем ОЗУ и жесткого диска, количество ядер, но никак не могу получить частоту ядер и разрешение камеры...

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20get%20cpu%20frequency%20programmatically&es_th=1
https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20get%20camera%20resolution%20programmatically&es_th=1
По первой-второй ссылке на запросы ответы на ваши вопросы.

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Информация об устройстве находится в файле #system/build.prop Гуглите